# Asterisk dynamic user agents on PSTN

Tags: voip, sip, asterisk

I'm creating small system as prove concept.
I need to configure few 5-10 call queues that will have mix of softphones (SIP) and normal gsm mobiles (PSTN) agents that can login and logout of queue.
I'm new to asterisk and whole voip. So after some research I think it is possible but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make login/logout for any user using asterisk applications `AddQueueMember()` and `RemoveQueueMember()`. For example PSTN user can be added in queue in such way:

```
exten => s,n,AddQueueMember(100,DAHDI/g0/1234567)
```

Also in queues for PSTN users most possibly you need to use custom device states, to make queue know if PSTN user already in queue call. It is done by function `DEVICE_STATE()` and `stateinterface` option of `AddQueueMember().`

Comment: Thank you for pointing in right direction. Now I know it's possible. Just as beginner to asterisk, all I did so far is to configure it trough freepbx with success. Could you point me where I should use this piece of configuration, please?

Comment: In freepbx you can do all this stuff from web interface: create you PSTN users as Custom extensions in FreePBX and use _Dynamic agents_ option in Queues